# Issue with creating a dictionary with Python and send it with a POST request

Tags: python, quotes

I am breaking my head for the lat 5 hours to find out how to create programmatically in Python a dictionary with specific values inside which I take from a list.
It sounds very easy (and it must be) but I am totally lost among errors with double quotes, string values and escaping characters. Any help would be really most appreciated. At least to understand what the heck I am doing wrong:

I will try to be as more detailed as possible. What I want to do is to create programmatically this:

```
    checkNode = {'statements':[
      {"statement":"MATCH (n:RealNode { id: "1" }) SET n.telecomType = 'P', n.buildingType= 'c' RETURN n"}, 
        {"statement":"MATCH (n:RealNode { id: "2" }) SET n.telecomType = 'P', n.buildingType= 'w' RETURN n"}, {...}, {...}
     ]}
```

The above its a Neo4J query, which I want to execute by sending a POST request like this:

```
    mkr = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(checkNode), headers=headers)
```

This is the procedure I follow:

1. First I convert the x into a string where x is:

   ```
   x = {"statement":"MATCH (n:RealNode { id: "1" }) SET n.telecomType = 'P', n.buildingType= 'c' RETURN n"}

   stringX = str(x)
   ```
2. Then I append this string into a list (mylist()). In the end the list has a number of strings inside.
3. Then I use the "join" method to join all the values inside the list and seperate them with comma:

   ```
   allStatement = ','.join(mylist)
   ```
4. Then I create the variable "checkNode" which is the one I will send to my POST request:

   ```
   checkNode = {'statements':[allStatement]}
   ```
5. Between the 4th and the 6th step I have tried a series of things such as replacing quotes and converting into string the variable "checkNode".
6. I sent the request:

   ```
   mkr = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(checkNode), headers=headers)
   print(mkr.text)
   ```

The request never is sent. 
I printed the checkNode variable and it looks like this:

```
    {'statements': ["{'statement': MATCH (n:RealNode { id: 'P3301041101' }) SET n.telecomType = 'P', n.buildingType= 'sealed' RETURN n},{'statement': CREATE (dsld:DslSldBconf {nodeType:'P3301041101', id: 'DSL-SLD48-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})}..."]}

    I think one of the problems here is the double quotes after the [
```

I have spent hours experimenting with different parameters but I can not make it work. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be messing around with manual string processing; the `json` module does all of that for you. What you want is more like:

```
x = {"statement":"MATCH (n:RealNode { id: "1" }) SET n.telecomType = 'P', n.buildingType= 'c' RETURN n"}
statement_list = [x]

# add any more statements to statement_list, probably using append()

checkNode = {'statements': statement_list}

mkr = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(checkNode), headers=headers)
print(mkr.text)
```

Also, be careful of what's an `str` and what's a `bytes`, for what you send over the network.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This seems to work but I still have a problem with the double quotes inside the statement. E.g. n:RealNode { id: "1" }). I get an invalid syntax error. If I change it to single quotes it works but as the id is created  like this: {id:"+idVariable+" ... I can not really change it.

Comment: The only thing to do here is escape them. `json` should do this automatically for quotes in the data; use \" for quotes in the script.